# Any examples of using Dagger (or another DI IoC container) in AAR?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, gradle, google-drive-api, dagger

Do you have a simple example of DI built on Gradle? I need to see setter injection used to express an optional dependecy, just as per the standard design pattern. Thank you

EDIT
To better define the context of the Q...
I already have my apk -OpenTweetSearch- on Google Play
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.new_year

I would like to integrate my Twitter OAuth 2.0 with Google Drive SDK OAuth 2.0.
I've found here the Gradle dependencies of Google Drive SDK: https://gist.github.com/johnscheible/5994719
There is an *exclusion* of transitive dependencies. "However, exclude feels like the sort of thing that an app developer might need but that ideally is avoided" (see [Gradle for Android, AARs, and Conditional Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938158/gradle-for-android-aars-and-conditional-dependencies)).
That's why am asking for code example of gradle and dependency injection in the context of Google Drive SDK: is would suffice also and example in c# .net WPF to help me.
In any case the code example is not the main point of my question and you could answer without any code examples: in fact a *Design Pattern* is something you should discuss before code implementation and it should be managed in a layer of abstraction separate from the layer of the building system. So I fail to understand why my Q is put on hold for a secondary point that is not the focus of my Q.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/paveldudka/dagger-otto-demo

Comment: oh, I see, I thought you asked for an example of using dagger with Graddle build system. unfortunately I don't have any samples of using dagger in aar :( Still trying to figure out how to do that myself

Comment: someone is trying to close this question as off-topic.. not sure why..

Comment: Just a suggestion, try to reword the title of your question to more accurately represent the question you're asking.

Comment: Dagger only supports constructor injection.

Answer (score 4):

I am Frank Du mentioned above. Thank you for checking my older blog. In fact, I've already adopted a new method, which is simpler and better.

The link has motivated me to share my android + gradle + dagger setup. Of coz I learned the tips from many sources, as I said in my blog. The github project covers quite a few topics, such as aar dependencies, module reuse, dagger code gen, etc. Here are the links:

1. Check out the source codes: https://github.com/frankdu/android-gradle-dagger-tutorial
2. The blog post: http://www.frankdu.com/blog/2014/01/18/tutorial-create-android-gradle-project-with-dagger/

So, hope it helps!

Comment: Even better. I learned more things at https://plus.google.com/+FrankDU3/posts/Vh4LWthj1Gp, and the github repo is updated. :-)