# Selectively compiling API into your executable for Android using ANT

Tags: android, ant

I was reading the developer docs for android wear and came across https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split

We are using ant and I was wondering if there is a way for us to do this using ant instead of gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Eclipse nor Ant support AARs, and Google is not distributing Play Services library projects in split versions (just the full library project). I doubt that Google will ever do so, considering that official support for Ant and Eclipse are discontinued.

Since [Android tools team members have been advising you to move off of Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938158/gradle-for-android-aars-and-conditional-dependencies/21059562#21059562) for a year, I really recommend that you do that soon.

In the meantime, you are welcome to attempt to [convert an AAR into a library project](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) for use with Ant.

Comment: we are planning to do the migration later this year. Thanks for the help im going to try and convert it to a library project. We are using android studio so thats 1 good thing. just need to do a gradle migration at some point in the near future. Will keep u posted about how this goes.